# jQuery + json time stopwatch

Tags: jquery, json

I need something like a stopwatch but I want him to get a date via json and print ( and constantly update ) the time since that date. I know that there is something like that out there but I have no idea how to google for it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some reading:

[MDN: Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[MDN: setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

And an example:

```js
var since = '2015-05-03T00:00:00'; // or any other valid value for a Date constructor
var sinceMs = new Date(since).getTime();
setInterval(function() {
    var ms = (new Date().getTime() - sinceMs);
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Seconds elapsed: ' + Math.round(ms / 1000);
}, 100);
```